# VM on Azure how to map public port 80 to private port 8080

Tags: azure, mapping, azure-virtual-machine, ports

I installed VM on Azure and I am trying to map public port 80 to private port 8080. I can find a lot of answers how to do do it using the old interface (using Endpoints) but I cannot find anything how to do it with the new portal (inbound and outbound security rules, Endpoins are gone). I created the inbound rules and I can access the app on port 8080 when I expose it, but I cannot figure out how to implement the translation from port 80 into private 8080.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems that with ARM it is no more possible to configure the port mapping, to avoid need of adding another server working as a load balancer, I created a rule in iptables (I am running Ubuntu server):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Not ideal but it works.

Comment: If this does not work for me does that mean there is something else wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a NIC associated with your VM. The NIC has a public IP address associated with it, and the NIC is in a network security group (NSG) that defines all the rules. Once you have attached the NSG to the NIC, you can go into the NSGs settings and modify the inbound and outbound security rules.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/737717/unable-to-configure-port-mapping-for-azure-availability-set-in-the-new-portal/737796#737796) shows a bit better what you are after..

Also here is a picture of what you are trying to do. It is possible...

[image]

Comment: It seems that with resource manager it is no more possible to configure the mapping of the ports. The only way is to set a load balancer and create forwarding rules there.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you are trying to do. Maybe you don't... But have a read of this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-nsg/

Comment: The last comment in the link that you originally provided answers my question: `2   
Just to complete your solution: if you need to do a port translation (i.e. different port on the public side than on the VM itself) for an ARM VM, you'll need to put the VM behind a load balancer and use Inbound NAT Rules for the port translation. – Pedro Perez Dec 1 '15 at 22:21`

Comment: Ok cool, sorry for my misunderstanding. At least you got your solution.